# Is there a way to forbid a base class method call in the derived class?

Tags: c++, oop

In c++ "protected" modifier allow method calls only in derived classes. Is it possible to implement inverse logic - prohibit calling a base class method in the derived classes? The code below illustrates what I want to get.

```
class Base
{
   int data;
protected:
   // This constructor should be called only in the derived classes
   Base(int d): data(d) { }
public:
   // This construcor can be called wherever except a derived classes!
   Base(): data(0) { }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
   // The developer must not forget to initialize "data"
   Derived() : Base(10) {}

   // I want to get a compilation error there
   Derived() : Base() {}
};
```

Comment: You cannot prevent a derived class from using a base class functionality if it is `public`.

Comment: this seems like a XY problem

Comment: It sounds like you may be using inheritance incorrectly (or in a way it's not supposed to be used). Can you expand on why you'd want to do this and what you *actually* want?

Comment: If you want your constructor to be accessible from anywhere (`public`) you can't also hide it from derived types (they are part of "anywhere"). Maybe there is a solution with an intermediate class between `Base` and `Derived` where the intermediate class doesn't have the constructor you want to block. But what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Access modifiers alone won't do what you ask.

Comment: @NathanOliver, You're right. But this is perhaps the another question) I only want to force the user to perform some additional actions wlile inheritting. For example, to avoid random errors.

Comment: I thought a static_assert could help.

Comment: @DmytroDadyka Sounds like you need a new design.  Forcing inherited object to do specific things is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @NathanOliver, Yes, it is rather a design problem. But nevertheless, I am interested in the possibility of achieving such behavior, albeit by "not  good" methods.

Comment: You could make the constructor private and create a class static function that calls the constructor. That would make it impossible for derived classes to use the constructor to construct themselves. So `Base j = Base::make();` would be legal and call that constructor.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, it is the best solution in my case.  Сan you answer so that I accept it?

Comment: @scohe001, everything is okay with inheritance. I just want to add protection against misuse of the class for those who are not reading comments in the code.

Comment: @DmytroDadyka "*I only want to force the user to perform some additional actions while inheriting*" - sounds like a possible job for pure virtual methods that derived classes must override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a XY problem. Although I do not recommend this (I recommend rethinking the design) I found (for better or worse) a solution inspired from the CRTP pattern:

```
template <class D = void>
class Base
{    
protected:

    int data;

protected:
    // This constructor should be called only in the derived classes
    template <class Der = D, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Base, Der>>>
    Base(int d): data(d) {}

public:
    // This constructor can be called wherever except a derived classes!
    template <class Der = D, class = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<Base, Der>>>
    Base(): data(0) { }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
    int mydata = 1;
public:
    // The developer must not forget to initialize "data"
    Derived() : Base(24) {}

    // I want to get a compilation error there
    //Derived() : Base() {} // (1) compilation error here
};
```

```
auto test()
{
    Base b1{};
    //Base b2{24}; // (2) compilation error here

    Derived d{};
}
```

Of course there are problems with this. For starters there is nothing stopping from creating a derived class as `class Derived : public Base<void>`.

And if you want, you can add a common base class

```
class Base_l0
{
};

template <class D = void>
class Base_l1 : Base_l0
{
};

class Derived : public Base_l1<Derived>
{
};
```

Comment: Interesting way, but not OOP.

Comment: @DmytroDadyka yes, but it can be worked around that. See edit

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to [...] prohibit calling a base class method in the derived classes?

Yes. By using private access specifier. Private names are accessible only to the class itself.

It is not *inverse logic* however. It is not possible for reduce accessibility of of otherwise public name from derived classes.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> // This construcor can be called wherever except a derived classes!
> ```

There is no way to do this.  A public function can be called by anyone and there is no SFINAE trick you can use to stop it if it is called by a derived class since the constructor has no idea where it is called from.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

In C++, there is only `public` `protected` and `private`. There is no middle ground. Your functions are either accessible from everywhere (`public`), from nowhere except the class itself (`private`), or from the class and its children (`protected`).

> I only want to force the user to perform some additional actions wlile inheritting [sic]. For example, to avoid random errors.

If calling the default constructor causes errors by calling it while inheriting from it, then then it is probable it causes errors when you are **not** inheriting from it. That means you probably shouldn't have this constructor as public anyway, if at all.